# Express adding Id when it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, server, sequelize.js

This is my code

```
const Message = connection.define("message", {
    room: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "Anonymous"
    },
    message: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false
    }
});

Message.create({
        name: req_user,
        room: req_room,
        message: req_message
}).catch((error) => { console.log(error)});
```

But as it happens, it throws this error:
**Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'**

And the problem is that it's trying to insert this id column out of nowhere:
sql: 'INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`,`room`,`name`,`message`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);',

Someone can help me?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with Express?  All you're showing in your question is code that has nothing to do with Express.

Comment: Well, i took a piece of my sequelize and express files and Message.create is inside routes so i just assume it was express, sorry xD i'm new to this, can you help me reformulate my question?

Comment: This is probably related to this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/741

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use

```
Message.removeAttribute('id');
```

Comment: looks like you found the solution for it. Kudos. In the future if you can also add more comments that help readers understand where the change was made to your code to fix the problem, it will be helpful.